Why am I getting an error when I want to run Firefox test atu

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void loadSystemProperties()' of abstract class org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId> //version of webdrivermanager
    <version>5.9.1</version>
</dependency> //hasan 

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId> //version of selenium
    <version>4.22.0</version>
</dependency>
Firefox version:  128.0.3

@Test
public void test2() {
    // Setup FirefoxDriver using WebDriverManager
    // Setup FirefoxDriver using WebDriverManager
    WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();

    // Create FirefoxOptions instance for advanced options
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.addArguments("--start-maximized"); // Start browser maximized
    // Add other options if needed (e.g., headless mode)

    // Create WebDriver instance using FirefoxDriver
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);

    ....

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // Close the browser
        driver.quit();
    }
}

What is the problem?

I believe webdrivermanager is deprecated as it's now built-in to Selenium.  That could be the issue.

Solutions : I used percy.
io.percy:percy-java-selenium is pulling in an old version of selenium-firefox-driver


org.seleniumhq.selenium
selenium-firefox-driver
4.22.0


io.percy
percy-java-selenium
2.0.5


org.seleniumhq.selenium
selenium-firefox-driver



relax @browsermator I dont used. Selenium Manager handles webdrivermanager that functionality
